# Arduino & RPi communication via GPIO

Tags: arduino-ide, pins, relay, raspberrypi

so I'm working on communication between arduino and RPi via GPIO pin. 
It's basically connecting them by using a cable jumper. So I have a 2 channel relay shield attached to my arduino, and I've been wondered how do I connect them to RPi. I need help for this problem, any advice would be appriciated. I'll post the GPIO pin below.
Thankyou
[image: 2 relay channel shield]

[image: RPi GPIO pin]

Comment: Do you really need the arduino? you can attach the relays to the rPi directly.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Thankyou for your answer, yes I do need the arduino, the relay is attached on my arduino,  you can attach the relay to RPi by using the cable jumper, but I don't really know how it work

Comment: Why not just use the serial cable?  Have you considered using the Raspberry Pi to program the Arduino then for communications also?  That's what I do for my solar plant modults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Arduino UNO. Pi's digital logic is at 3.3 V and that of Arduino Uno is at 5 V. Anyway to send data from Pi to UNO, you can connect the pins directly. UNO can recognise both the logic levels of Pi's output. But to receive data from UNO to Pi, make sure you build a voltage divider using resistors, that brings 5V output from UNO's pin to 3.3 V. Also the grounds of both Pi and UNO should be connected to each other.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. The thing is I've attached relay channel shield on top of my arduino. So i just connect them like
RPi           pin 1 to   Arduino GND 5v
Like that?

Comment: why are you using relay shield?

Comment: @tbh Using relay shiled so i can attach another device called xbee(cc2530) for wireless transmission

Comment: to send data from pi to arduino and then send that data wirelessly via zigbee?

Comment: What on earth does a realy shield have to do with connecting an xBee? I think you are a little confused about what you actually want to do and are suffering from a severe case of xy-problem.

Comment: using zigbee for wireless transmission to another device

Comment: If you want to use an xBee for Pi communication then connect the xBee to the pi. It uses UART communication (very simple to wire up) or you can use a USB "explorer" board to plug it in to the USB socket. They use simple AT commands to configure them that are well documented. There is no role for the Arduino here.

Comment: We actually don't understand what do you want to do. You said you want to use ZigBee for wireless communication. You are not mentioning what data have to be transferred from where to where.

Comment: @Majenko there's no role of xBee here, it just between arduino(attached with relay shield) and RPi

Comment: @MITURAJ sorry for missunderstand, I'm not using this xBee things now, I've just thinking how do I connect my arduino that was attached with relay shield to RPi by using GPIO port. Why I use relay shield? Because It's for my next project, and also what for xBee it's also for my next project

Comment: Okay, remove the shield from UNO, zigbee etc and connect Pi and UNO as mentioned in this answer to make them communicate. Connections depend on what are the components you use and what you want to do with it.

Comment: @MITURAJ so for example RPi will send pin 4 HIGH, and arduino will receive the information, I've write the code, the problem is , how do I pin the right GPIO port from my  RPi to arduino. The thing is my next project and this problem right still have some sort of relation , so I need to attach my relay shield to my arduino

Comment: Answer for that is what I have given here.

Comment: @MITURAJ thankyou , i really appreciate that, also thanks for your time for spending in here

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking really makes no sense at all.

You are starting from the mid-point of your project and wondering how to communicate using bare GPIOs without really knowing *what it is you want to communicate* and *what you want to do with that data* - or at least you haven't made any of that clear to us.

It is unclear what you want to do with the shield from the Pi. Do you want to control the relays on it by sending instructions from the Pi? Do you want the Pi to send and receive data through the XBee? Either way the Arduino is pretty redundant in the system and in fact gets in the way more than is useful.

If it's just relays you want then it would be far simpler to wire cheap relay modules direct to the GPIOs of the Pi - then you don't have to worry about "how to communicate" - you just turn the relays on and off.

If you want to communicate with the XBee there are far simpler shields available that will plug directly into a Pi. Indeed, there are some good shields around for the Pi ("Hats" I think they call them) which give you an Arduino footprint and an XBee socket together.

The Arduino is completely pointless in this system. And anyway, if you wanted to make the two systems communicate there are far easier ways than with bare GPIO pins. Serial, for a start. The simplest ever method is to just plug the Arduino into the Pi's USB. That way it gets power and data all in one go. Just like using it with a computer.